# Do I have to file California tax return for worldwide income?

Tags: united-states, taxes, california

I'm a new immigrant (green card) to US, and not live in California yet. I use my friend's home in CA as the mailing address for receiving my letters, packages, and California ID. I plan to move to California and work there in US next year. I know California taxes on worldwide income, and I do not have any income source from California. So do I need to file tax return in California on my worldwide income or capital gain of 2014 in next year?

Comment: are you physically in the US? Where do you live?

Comment: I am not physically in US. I went to CA for immigration processing and applying for ID and something before immigration visa expired, and then return to my home country to continue my job. I will move after I get a new job in US.

Comment: what ID did you apply for?

Comment: I applied for California ID because I'll need to open the bank account or something like that when I move to there.

Comment: Well, then you're screwed.